# how to detect and extract hidden message fir images steganography

Tags: netbeans

i was developed a tool for steganalysis images but i still do not find a suitable coding for that tool. The aim of the tool to detect hidden message in steganography images and extract it. I also used netbeans software for that tool. So, can u help me to fix the problems.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Did you write some code but it's not working as intended? Show us your code and tell us what the problem is exactly. Do you intend developing a tool, but don't know how to code it and haven't found any code online? That would make it an off-topic question for this site. Please edit your question and clarify your problem.